# How to find bestprice combinations from two tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to tables with similar data. One serving outgoing connections, one serving incomings.

```
table_out:
from_,to_,departure,price,name...

table_in:
from_,to_,depature,price,name...
```

I want to join those tables so that I can create journeys from one point to a destination, and return to the starting point afterwards. I'd like to get any combinations possible.

Therefore the following query works:

```
WITH outs AS(
    SELECT from_, to_, departure, min(price)
    FROM table_out
    GROUP BY from_, to_, departure
),
ins AS (
    SELECT from_, to_, departure, min(price)
    FROM table_in
    GROUP BY from_, to-, departure
)

SELECT DISTINCT on (from_, to_, departure, return)
    a.from_, a.to_,
    a.departure, b.departure as return,
    a.price + b.price as totalprice
FROM outs a JOIN ins b ON (
    a.from_ = b.to_
    AND a.to_ = b.from_
    AND a.departure  <= b.departure
)
```

BUT: what if I want to select additional values from the minimum combinations found? Like a.name, b.name? I cannot add those parameters to the `WITH` subselect as I do not want to `group by` these properties.

Anyways, as soon as I have all "bestprice" combination, I'm interested in that additional columns of each bestprice item selected.

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`.  In your case:

```
WITH outs AS (
      SELECT t.*
      FROM (SELECT t.*,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY from_, to_, departure ORDER BY price DESC) as seqnum
            FROM table_out
           ) t
      WHERE seqnum = 1 
     ),
     ins AS (
      SELECT t.*
      FROM (SELECT t.*,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY from_, to_, departure ORDER BY price DESC) as seqnum
            FROM table_in
           ) t
      WHERE seqnum = 1 
     )
SELECT DISTINCT on (from_, to_, departure, return)
       a.from_, a.to_,
       a.departure, b.departure as return,
       (a.price + b.price) as totalprice,
       . . .
FROM outs a
     JOIN ins b
     ON a.from_ = b.to_ AND
        a.to_ = b.from_ AND
        a.departure  <= b.departure
ORDRE BY from_, to_, departure, return;
```

Or, alternatively, you could use `DISTINCT ON` in the subqueries:

```
WITH outs AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (from_, to_, departure), t.*
      FROM table_out
           ) t
      WHERE seqnum = 1 
      ORDER BY from_, to_, departure, price
     ),
 . . .
```

As a note:  This answers your question.  However, your method of getting the least expensive round trip is not guaranteed to work.  Consider a situation such as these three connetions:

1. A --> B 10:00 a.m. @100
2. A --> B 10:00 p.m. @50
3. B --> A 1:00 p.m.  @100

Your method would choose (2) for the cheapest outbound connection.  However, it is too late in the day and there is no subsequent return.  If you want to solve this problem, ask another question with sample data and desired results.  This answer addresses how to get additional data.

Comment: Regarding your sidenote: I don't see the problem: if there is no return connection, the combination is just skipped, isn't it? that would be fine for me.

Comment: Problem with the additional `DISTINCT ON` select the performance is 3x worse. Which is critical as each table contains like 10mio rows.

Comment: The first approach does not work saying: `column "from_" must occur in a GROUP-BY-Clause or used in an aggregate function.`

Comment: @membersound . . . The last point is that the cheapest option is missed -- there is a pair, but the pair does not consist of the cheapest connection in each direction.